# Running python script using a cron job

Tags: python, cron

Ok so I am trying to run a python script every 3 hours using cron, but I think it's not working. I know this because my script should produce some csv files and I cannot find them anywhere or the logs, plus my script is also reading from another file like (which I think is part of the issue):

```
with open('json_file.json') as f:
...
```

so if I try to run my script from a different directory with

```
> python ~/my_working_dir/my_script.py
```

I get a FileNotFoundError

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'json_file.json'

my job goes something like this:

```
SHELL=/usr/bin/zsh
0 */3 * * * python ~/my_working_dir/my_script.py > ~/my_working_dir/cronlogs/cron.log
```

I have little experience with crontab so I am not sure about the source of the problem, but my first guess is that I need to add some path somewhere

Hope someone could help

Comment: don't provide relative path ie don't use `~` , provide the full path to the file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think would be better if you gave open() a full path for that file.
I would specify the full path to python as well.

`1 */12 * * * /usr/bin/python3 /root/telesend.py >> /root/cron.log 2>&1`

this is my example which is working perfectly well
take a look at [link](https://crontab.guru/) for correct schedule expressions

Comment: Thanks! This helps a lot
I also just noticed that my working dir is mispelled and properly written in the crontab :s
Damn you dyslexia!

Comment: test your script set after 2-3 minutes and if it works make this accepted answer so that others notice